# How to Define Hash Value for Sequence of Functions (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, function-pointers

I've got a piece of software that does various operations on small images (bitmaps, sprites, textures, whatever you want to call them). In order to prevent **vast** duplication of effort, I would like to setup a cache so that once a particular source image goes through a sequence of operations, it can simple be recalled from cache instead of going through the same sequence for each of the possibly hundreds of thousands of times it is needed.

I would like the cache to be a map between the "hash value" of the specific sequence of operations(with parameters) and the actual data. I'm thoroughly stumped as to how to "hash" functions, though. This is implemented in c++11, so some of the Pythonic solutions that occurred to me do no work since they are dependent on first class functions and introspection. What is the c++ solution?

An example:

1. `src1 = load("path/file.png");`
2. `convert_space(copy_src1, LABA);`
3. `adj_hue(copy_src1, 45.0f);`
4. `src2 = load("path/file2.png");`
5. `compose_over(copy_src1, src2, dst);`
6. **cache `dst`**
7. *profit* :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you want a unique identifier for an image with a given series of operations applied.

The most straight forward approach is to just give each operation it's own token, and then append that token to the original image's identifier, for each operation applied to it.

For example, if you have an image `test.png`, and you apply operation A and B, you could use `test.png_A_B` as a unique identifier.

Comment: The "images" are never written out to the filesystem, but are kept in buffers (`img` object wrappers actually). I could add a variable to the wrapper to track it's history; but without some sort of hash it would probably be just as efficient not to cache.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the images come from, but you probably have some sort of identifier for each image; the idea is to just append to that identifier and use that as your 'hash'. I just used file names as an example.

Comment: For an image, you apply a sequence of functions. Each function will have specific parameters. I wonder if each transformation function could compute a unique hash of its parameters? You then associate that hash with each function, and store a list of them. How many possible transformation functions are there?

Comment: @JeffreyDeLeo There are probably a ~15 or so basic operations with many having numerous trivial overloads. I.e., adj_hue(img& src, int degrees) and adj_hue(img& src, float radians).

Comment: @justinzane: Using your example code, dauphic's approach and a RPN-like order of appending operations gives something like "path/file.png convert_space(LABA) adj_hue(45) path/file2.png compose_over".  That string is not itself the *hash* - it's the *key* - you map the key to your associated image in your `unordered_map`, and let the implementation hash the key however it wants.  If some operations are commutative, you may want to standardise the order or arguments so the keys match.